# Can I leave boneless chicken breast flat in freezer overnight?

Tags: freezing, chicken-breast

I buy refrigerated chicken breasts and cut them into smaller pieces, lay flat on a cake pan and freeze overnight, then separate them and put into individual bags in the morning. Does this cause other food in freezer to get contaminated?

Answer (score 2):

Other food will get contaminated if they come into physical contact with the chicken, but as long as you keep the food separate that will be fine. It's not that good for the chicken, putting meat and poultry into the freezer without protection will damage it, however if it's only overnight it's no big deal. I'd still put some plastic wrap over the tray to protect it.

Comment: Or just bag them up before freezing and then put them flat on that pan if the flat shape is the reason to freeze them like that ;)